# Create graph from GVD (edges and vertices)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, graph-theory, robotics

Given a binary image of a map with obstacles (black pixels), the objective is to create a Voronoi diagram graph. So far, this is done using the brushfire algorithm, from which the GVD can be extracted using the Laplacian operator (i.e. the gradient); the process is demonstrated below and the C++ code can be found in [this file](https://github.com/martinandrovich/rb-pro5/blob/45be4b23db1b910f8ac6b0facc864d5b0ca3ea95/src/modules/geometry.h#L365).

[image: gvd process]

The goal is now to use the GVD (image 3) to create an adjacency graph, being basically a graph-like data structure with the Voronoi vertices as nodes and edges being the paths between nodes.

My question is, what is the most optimal way of doing this? So far, I have detected vertices of the GVD using the `cv::findContours` method as shown in the last image, and the idea is to now remove any near-duplicate vertices and try connecting the nodes using the black pixels and a line iterator.

Is there a better way?